# Kivy: weird Button on_touch_down behaviour?

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a Trivia app, each question has 4 options attached. For each option, it is associated with an `OptionButton` class. 4 `OptionButton` instances are stored inside a grid layout `Choices`. What I want is that: if user press the correct button, then it should print `selt.text, self.answer`. But it seems that all the buttons share the user's touch at the same time, why is this?

Full code:

```
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


trivias = (("What is the capital city of Singapore?", ["Singapore", \
                                                       "Bukit Timah", \
                                                       "Raffles Place", \
                                                       "Orchard Road"], "Singapore") , \
            ("What year is Indonesia's Independence", ["1946", \
                                                        "1964", \
                                                        "1945", \
                                                        "1899"], "1945") )


class OptionButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, option):
        super().__init__(text = option)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super().on_touch_down(touch)
        if self.parent.answer == self.text:
            print(self.text, self.parent.answer)


class Question(Label):
    pass


class Choices(GridLayout):
    options = ListProperty([""])
    def __init__(self, options, answer):
        super().__init__(rows = 2, cols = 2)
        self.a = OptionButton(option = options[0])
        self.b = OptionButton(option = options[1])
        self.c = OptionButton(option = options[2])
        self.d = OptionButton(option = options[3])
        self.add_widget(self.a)
        self.add_widget(self.b)
        self.add_widget(self.c)
        self.add_widget(self.d)
        self.answer = answer
        self.options = options

    def on_options(self, instance, new_options):
        self.a.text = new_options[0]
        self.b.text = new_options[1]
        self.c.text = new_options[2]
        self.d.text = new_options[3]


class AppGrid(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        rand = random.randint(0, 1)
        self.question = Question(text = trivias[rand][0])
        self.choices = Choices(trivias[rand][1], trivias[rand][2])
        self.add_widget(self.question)
        self.add_widget(self.choices)
        self.question.size_hint = (0.5, 0.3)
        self.question.pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.7}
        self.choices.size_hint = (0.5, 0.6)
        self.choices.pos_hint = {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.1}

    def newquestion(self):
        rand = random.randint(0, 1)
        self.question.text = trivias[rand][0]
        self.choices.options = trivias[rand][1]
        self.choices.answer = trivias[rand][2]



class TriviaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = AppGrid()
        return root


app = TriviaApp()
app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud not use `on_touch` events with buttons. Unless you plan to handle if the touch is inside a specific boundary by yourself. `on_touch` affects the whole window.

Use the buttons `on_press` or `on_release` methods instead.